# Starting on boot Ruby on Rails server running on Raspberry Pi Raspbian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, raspberry-pi, debian

I am running Ruby on Rails server on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. I can start the production Rails server with this command
`rvmsudo rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80 -e production`.
What is the best practice for running a production Ruby on Rails server on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian? Ideally the solution would be resilient to reboots.

Comment: What's the problem? I don't see a question so much as a survey.

Comment: I'm interested in best practices and to prevent "run `rails server`" answers, I wanted to demonstrate that I know how to start the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your command `rvmsudo rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80 -e production` to the file /etc/rc.local using your favourite text editor or by using the command `echo "rvmsudo rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80 -e production" >> /etc/rc.local` after this execute `/etc/rc.local` to reload the file if the server is not started :-)